# *ngIf inside *ngfor to validate each item of the for loop

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

```
<li *ngFor="let year of paper?.years" class="list-group-item">                                                
                    <div>
                        <a routerLink="/viewpdf/{{year.questionPaper.fileId}}">Question Paper - {{year.formattedYear }}</a> 
                        <a href="{{ downloadUrl }}/{{year.questionPaper.fileId}}" class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div> 
                        <a routerLink="/viewpdf/{{year.markScheme.fileId}}"> || Mark Scheme - {{year.formattedYear }}</a>                        
                        <a href="{{ downloadUrl }}/{{year.markScheme.fileId}}" class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></a>
                    </div>   
</li>
```

The above code is working fine. But I want to check each fileId, if its null or not. If null then the links will not generate and vice versa.

I have setted *ngIf, below is a code sample. But its not working.

```
<li *ngFor="let year1 of paper?.years" class="list-group-item">  

                    <div *ngif="year.questionPaper.fileId != ''">
                        <a routerLink="/viewpdf/{{year.questionPaper.fileId}}">Question Paper - {{year.formattedYear }}</a> 
                        <a href="{{ downloadUrl }}/{{year.questionPaper.fileId}}" class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngif="year.markScheme.fileId != ''"> 
                        <a routerLink="/viewpdf/{{year.markScheme.fileId}}"> || Mark Scheme - {{year.formattedYear }}</a>                        
                        <a href="{{ downloadUrl }}/{{year.markScheme.fileId}}" class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></a>
                    </div>                      

                </li>
```

I have tried several other ways, but nothing is working. Like : 
defining ng-template.

Comment: What you want to check? `null` or **empty string**?

Comment: Another typo in `*ngif="year.markScheme.fileId = ''"` `=` should be `==`

Comment: typo *ngFor="let year1 of paper?.years" should it not be year instead of year1?

Comment: It has Solved! Thank you Guys!!

Comment: Pleasure Abdur. Please mark any one answer right.

Comment: Yes, I have marked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to use == or !=.

Just modify your code with the below code.

```
<li *ngFor="let year1 of paper?.years" class="list-group-item">      
     <div *ngIf="year.questionPaper.fileId">
        <a routerLink="/viewpdf/{{year.questionPaper.fileId}}">Question Paper - {{year.formattedYear }}</a> 
        <a href="{{ downloadUrl }}/{{year.questionPaper.fileId}}" class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></a>
     </div>
     <div *ngIf="year.markScheme.fileId"> 
        <a routerLink="/viewpdf/{{year.markScheme.fileId}}"> || Mark Scheme - {{year.formattedYear }}</a>                        
        <a href="{{ downloadUrl }}/{{year.markScheme.fileId}}" class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></a>
    </div>                        
</li>
```

**Explanation:**

`<div *ngIf="year.questionPaper.fileId">` // This will automatically check for **null, undefined and empty string**.

Comment: It has Solved! Thank you!! 

All answers are right. But as this answer is more appropriate and descriptive I am marking this as right answer.

Comment: What about `0` (Zero)?

Comment: Change condition to: <div *ngIf="year.questionPaper.fileId || year.questionPaper.fileId === 0">

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo. use *ngIf

```
<div *ngIf="year.questionPaper.fileId != ''">
                        <a routerLink="/viewpdf/{{year.questionPaper.fileId}}">Question Paper - {{year.formattedYear }}</a> 
                        <a href="{{ downloadUrl }}/{{year.questionPaper.fileId}}" class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="year.markScheme.fileId = ''"> 
                        <a routerLink="/viewpdf/{{year.markScheme.fileId}}"> || Mark Scheme - {{year.formattedYear }}</a>                        
                        <a href="{{ downloadUrl }}/{{year.markScheme.fileId}}" class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></a>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Great! the syntax error is gone. WHAT A SILLY Mistake I made. Thank you very much. But probably its not checking the fileId is empty or not. Can you guide me please?

Comment: It has Solved! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

An extension to Syedur answer,

`*ngIf="year.markScheme.fileId = ''"` 
in the above line you missed `==` or `===` but not `=`. Can be `=`

Comment: It has Solved! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Surjeet Bhadauriyas answer led me to the right path with my problem.
Still i wanna reference this question with following error: **"Cannot read property name of undefined"**, because searching for this error brought me to mostly async data problems, which this is not:

The array has more data points than the dictionary, i want to iterate (ngFor) over the array and access the dictionary except (ngIf) when there is no datapoint.

**component**

```
letters: string[] = ["A", "B", "C"];
dictionary: { [key: string]: { name: string } } = {};

ngOnInit() {
    this.dictionary["A"] = { name: "Alpha" };
    this.dictionary["B"] = { name: "Beta" };
}
```

**template (does not work)**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let letter of letters">
    <ng-container *ngIf="letter!=C">
        <pre>{{letter}}</pre>
        <pre>{{dictionary[letter].name}}</pre>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

**template (does work)**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let letter of letters">
    <ng-container *ngIf="dictionary[letter]">
        <pre>{{letter}}</pre>
        <pre>{{dictionary[letter].name}}</pre>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```